# How Are Items From An Irregularly Shaped Array Accessed From Memory?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, indexing

I know n-dimensional arrays are stored in memory as a 1-d array like:
`[[5,4],[2,3]]`
could be stored as
`5 4 2 3`
and items can be easily accessed knowing the shape of the array.
But if you have an array like:
`[[5,4],[1,2,3]]`
I would guess it is still stored like:
`5 4 1 2 3`

How would you access an item from this array with an irregular shape? Is there a quick formula for it?

Or is it stored more like:
`obj1 obj2`
and that sends you to

```
obj1 = [5,4]
obj2 = [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays.

Comment: It's like you show at the end.

Comment: Lists don't need to be stored in a single, contiguous chunk of memory. As for accessing an n-dimensional list, to get the item with value `1` from your example, it would be `example[1][0]`.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I was sloppy with the names. So there is no nice formula for it, it is just 1-d with objects inside of it?

Comment: Yes. There are arrays in numpy, they're probably stored contiguously, but they also don't allow irregular shapes.

Comment: @Ouroborus I know how to get values from irregular lists in Python, I was wondering what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Nested lists are *not* stored as a contiguous 1D chunk of memory. Your initial premise is incorrect. Multidimensional NumPy arrays *can* be backed by a contiguous chunk of memory (though they don't have to be), but multidimensional NumPy arrays cannot be jagged. (The closest thing would be an object array containing lists, but this is almost always a bad idea.)

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Numpy arrays do allow irregular shapes if their type is `object`, those were the arrays I was wondering about. I assume their items are accessed the second way.

Comment: "Numpy arrays do allow irregular shapes if their type is object" - no they don't. The array is always a fixed grid. Objects it holds references to can be whatever. (Again, arrays containing lists are almost always a bad idea.)

Comment: @user2357112 You are right, that was badly phrased. You mentioned that Numpy arrays did not have to be stored as 1d chunks, how else can they be stored?

Comment: All dimensions must have a consistent stride, but there's no contiguity requirement. For example, after `a = numpy.arange(10); b = a[::2]`, `b` is a non-contiguous array.

Comment: @user2357112 So `b` would not be stored as `0 2 4 6 8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My second example seems to be the right one. It would not be irregularly shaped. The array would just have items with different sizes. Accessing item `[0][1]` of `[[1,2],[3,4,5]]` would send the computer to `[1,2]` as item 0 and then `[1]` of `[1,2]` can be found normally. The list would not be represented as `1 2 3 4 5`.